# Firebase Firestore not repsonding to EventListener

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a RecyclerView.Adapter in my code which is used to set elements in my layout file, but due to an UNKNOWN error, I am not able to display those elements. I am able to retrieve the data from Firebase, able to reach the onBindViewHolder but, there are no end results.

**Logcat**

```
D/HomeViewModel: Data was added to the LiveData List.[secondQuestion, question]
D/HomeAdapter: onCreateViewHolder
    onBindViewHolder
```

**HomeAdapter.java**

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull HomeAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
         if (mQuestions.isEmpty()) {
              String question = mQuestions.get(position);
              holder.question.setText(question);
          }
}
```

**HomeFragment.java**

```
homeViewModel.getmQuestionsData().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<List<String>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<String> mQuestionList) {
                mQuestion.addAll(mQuestionList);

                // TODO: The FUCKING Bug is around here
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

**HomeViewModel.java**

```
MutableLiveData<List<String>> getmQuestionsData() {
        repository.getPredictiousCol()
                //.whereEqualTo("exists","true")
//                
                .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                        if (e != null) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Question could not be retrieved " + e);
                            mQuestionsData = null;
                            return;
                        }
                        List<String> questionList = new ArrayList<>();
                        assert queryDocumentSnapshots != null;
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot doc : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                            if (doc.get("question") != null) {
                                questionList.add((String) doc.get("question"));
                            }
                        }
                        mQuestionsData.postValue(questionList);
                        Log.d(TAG, "Data was added to the LiveData List." + questionList);
                    }
                });
        return mQuestionsData;
    }
```

Comment down below if you want more of my code or any other related queries.

**THANK YOU!**

Comment: Shlok...sounds silly but have you checked your If statement onBindViewHolder...what does the console show within the else area / is it reaching your If statement?

Answer (score 1):

I think your error is here:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull HomeAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
         if (mQuestions.isEmpty()) {
              String question = mQuestions.get(position);
              holder.question.setText(question);
          }
}
```

You're in essence saying if you have nothing in your list then set the questions to your list.... It should say:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull HomeAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
         if (!mQuestions.isEmpty()) {
              String question = mQuestions.get(position);
              holder.question.setText(question);
          }
}
```

note the ! before mQuestions.isEmpty() meaning if the mQuestion is not empty...